# What's wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: php, errors

I have created a custom map view page on my classified ads website and I seem to be having issues with the page loading, here is the code for the page.

```
    <?php



                                $featured_query = '';
                                if(!empty($stm_listing_filter['featured'])) {
                                    $featured_query = $stm_listing_filter['featured'];
                                }


                                $listing = $stm_listing_filter['listing_query'];

                                $filter_badges = $stm_listing_filter['badges'];

                                $filter_links = stm_get_car_filter_links();

                                $listing_filter_position = get_theme_mod('listing_filter_position', 'left');
                                if(!empty($_GET['filter_position']) and $_GET['filter_position'] == 'right') {
                                    $listing_filter_position = 'right';
                                }


                            $regular_price_label = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'regular_price_label', true);
                            $special_price_label = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'special_price_label',true);

                            $price = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'price',true);
                            $sale_price = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'sale_price',true);

                            $car_price_form_label = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'car_price_form_label', true);

                            $data_price = '0';


                            if(!empty($price)) {
                                $data_price = $price;
                            }

                            if(!empty($sale_price)) {
                                $data_price = $sale_price;
                            }

                            if(empty($price) and !empty($sale_price)) {
                                $price = $sale_price;
                            }

                            $mileage = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'mileage',true);

                            $data_mileage = '0';

                            if(!empty($mileage)) {
                                $data_mileage = $mileage;
                            }

                            $taxonomies = stm_get_taxonomies();

                            $categories = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), $taxonomies);

                            $classes = array();

                            if(!empty($categories)) {
                                foreach($categories as $category) {
                                    $classes[] = $category->slug.'-'.$category->term_id;
                                }
                            }

                            //Fav

                            $cars_in_favourite = array();
                            if(!empty($_COOKIE['stm_car_favourites'])) {
                                $cars_in_favourite = $_COOKIE['stm_car_favourites'];
                                $cars_in_favourite = explode(',', $cars_in_favourite);
                            }

                            if(is_user_logged_in()) {
                                $user = wp_get_current_user();
                                $user_id = $user->ID;
                                $user_added_fav = get_the_author_meta('stm_user_favourites', $user_id );
                                if(!empty($user_added_fav)) {
                                    $user_added_fav = explode(',', $user_added_fav);
                                    $cars_in_favourite = $user_added_fav;
                                }
                            }

                            $car_already_added_to_favourite = '';
                            $car_favourite_status = esc_html__('Add to favorites', 'motors');

                            if(!empty($cars_in_favourite) and in_array(get_the_ID(), $cars_in_favourite)){
                                $car_already_added_to_favourite = 'active';
                                $car_favourite_status = esc_html__('Remove from favorites', 'motors');
                            }

                            $show_favorite = get_theme_mod('enable_favorite_items', true);

                            //Compare
                            $show_compare = get_theme_mod('show_listing_compare', true);

                            $cars_in_compare = array();
                            if(!empty($_COOKIE['compare_ids'])) {
                                $cars_in_compare = $_COOKIE['compare_ids'];
                            }

                            $car_already_added_to_compare = '';
                            $car_compare_status = esc_html__('Add to compare', 'motors');

                            if(!empty($cars_in_compare) and in_array(get_the_ID(), $cars_in_compare)){
                                $car_already_added_to_compare = 'active';
                                $car_compare_status = esc_html__('Remove from compare', 'motors');
                            }

                            /*Media*/
                            $car_media = stm_get_car_medias(get_the_id());
                            ?>

                                                    <div class="stm-isotope-sorting" style="display: none;">
                                                        <?php while($listing->have_posts()):
                                                            get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list', 'loop' );
                                                        endwhile; ?>
                                                    </div>


                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
                            <script>
                            $(document).ready(function() {


                                    var markersInfo = $('.ia-card').map(function() {

                                            var info = {
                                                id: $(this).data('map-id'),
                                                address: $(this).data('map-address'),
                                                title: $(this).data('map-title'),
                                                price: $(this).data('map-price'),
                                                latitude: $(this).data('map-latitude'),
                                                longitude: $(this).data('map-longitude'),
                                                html: "<img src=" + $(this).data('map-image') + ">",
                                                link: $(this).data("map-link"),
                                          contentHtml:  "<div class='image'>" + "<img src=" + $(this).data('map-image') + ">" + "</div>" + '<b>' + $(this).data('map-title') + '</b><br>' + "<div class='changeprice'><div style='display: none;' class='currency-selector'></div>" + $(this).data('map-price') + "</div>" + "<br><a href='" + $(this).data("map-link") + "'>More>></a>"
                                            };

                                        return info;
                                    }).get();


                                var distinctMarkerInfo = [];
                                markersInfo.forEach(function(item) {
                                    if (!distinctMarkerInfo.some(function(distinct) {
                                            return distinct.id == item.id;
                                        })) distinctMarkerInfo.push(item);
                                });

                                initGoogleMap(distinctMarkerInfo);




                                // GMAP ON SEARCH RESULTS PAGE
                                function initGoogleMap(markersInfo) {

                                    var mapOptions = {
                                        // zoom: 2,
                                        // center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.334430, -7.736673) // center of Ireland
                                    },
                                    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
                                    mapElement = document.getElementById('stm_map_results'),
                                    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
                                    markerList = []; // create an array to hold the markers

                                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


                                    var iconBase = 'http://throttlebuddies.com/wp-content/themes/motors/assets/images/';



                                    $.each(markersInfo, function(key, val) {
                                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            //map: map,
                                            position: {lat: parseFloat(val.latitude), lng: parseFloat(val.longitude)},
                                            title: val.title,
                                            icon: iconBase + 'single.png',
                                            info: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                                content: val.contentHtml
                                            })

                                        });


                                        markerList.push(marker); // add the marker to the list

                                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                            marker.info.open(map, marker);
                                            });


                                        loc = new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
                                            bounds.extend(loc);
                                    });


                                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                                        map.panToBounds(bounds);

                                  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerList, {
                                  imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
                                  });


                                };


                                });
                            </script>



                            <div id="stm_map_results" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>


                            <style>
                            .stm-isotope-sorting {
                                position: relative;
                                height: 600px !important;
                            }
                            </style>
```

The page loads fine however when I get rid of the following code. But I need this code to populate the map.

```
    <div class="stm-isotope-sorting" style="display: none;">
                                                        <?php while($listing->have_posts()):
                                                            get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list', 'loop' );
                                                        endwhile; ?>
                                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
while($listing->have_posts()):
    get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list', 'loop' );
endwhile;
```

will never terminate, because `$listing->have_posts()` will never be false. You need `$listing->the_post()` to advance the loop to the next post in each iteration. Then, when the last post is reached, `$listing->have_posts()` will be false and the loop will end.

```
while($listing->have_posts()):
    $listing->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list', 'loop' );
endwhile;
```

Comment: It still didn't work for some reason, I initially had that in the code but I got rid of it because I thought it would make a difference but I forgot to add it back in to ask this question...

Comment: Do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: No but I will turn it on now thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.7.0 with no alternative available

Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.

Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI'

These are the 3 errors that are showing up but I think the first 2 have always been there before this current issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing the while and endwhile from the code and just used the template part.

From ->

```
while($listing->have_posts()):
$listing->the_post();
get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list', 'loop' );
endwhile;
```

To ->

```
get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list', 'loop' );
```